# Nginx PHP-FPM Basic Auth

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, http-basic-authentication

I have `nginx` with `php-fpm` installed on `Debian Squeeze`.
Directory tree is:

- /var/www/mysite

  - index.php
  - secret_folder_1

    - admin.php
    - static.html
  - secret_folder_2

    - admin.php
    - static.html
  - pictures
  - img01.jpg

I need to close `secret_folder_1` and `secret_folder_2` with `basic_auth`.
Now config looks like:

```
location ~ /secret_folder_1/.+\.php$
{
        root /var/www/mysite/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/mysite$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.passwd;
}

location ~ /secret_folder_1/.*
{
        root /var/www/mysite/;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.passwd;
}
```

Same config for `secret_folder_2`.

Is it normal? I mean, first location for serving `php` files in restricted folder, and second location for serving static files.

Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nested locations may be better:

```
location /secret_folder_1 {
    root /var/www/mysite/;
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.passwd;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Please notice that you should define SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter with `$document_root` variable instead of hardcoded `/var/www/mysite/`:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: More importantly, `root` must be set before `$document_root` is used, otherwise `$document_root` is empty.